# inconsistent behavior of beautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, findall

I am trying to make a python file which gives real time stock updates.
I tried `for l in code.findAll('span', {'id' : 'ChangePercent'}):` for :

```
<span id="ChangePercent">-0.71%</span>
```

it worked,
source : `money.rediff.com/`
but using same technique on yahoo finance doesn't work..
i.e.

```
price = code.findAll('span', {'class' : 'yfi-price-change-green'})
```

fails to find : `<span class="yfi-price-change-green">(1.95%)</span>`

source : `finance.yahoo.com/`

the two codes :
rediff : http://ideone.com/kslILJ
yahoo : http://ideone.com/egGQLv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you are looking for on the Yahoo Finance Page are updated periodically via a streaming API call in the browser. You would not get these values by just requesting the `Reliance Industries Ltd (RELIANCE.NS)` url using `urllib` or `requests`.

The least complex option would be to automate a real browser using [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/):

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>>
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=RELIANCE.NS&ql=0')
>>> for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('yfi-price-change-green'):
...     print(element.text)
... 
0.55%
0.40%
```

Comment: thanx for useful inputs alecxe, just one ques, even if html sorce updates on yahoo source, findAll should be able to locate `findAll('span', {'class' : 'yfi-price-change-green'})` like it does on rediff page,as only the stock price is altered, so what is it that differentiates the two cases..

Comment: @FreakAtNs these two cases are completely different in terms of the techniques used to form and render the page, deliver the rates, update the rates etc. Yahoo definitely makes it more difficult to automate/scrape.

Comment: got it @alecxe, i was inclined towards rediff as its easier to retrieve data, i intend to print list of various stocks prices, with names of stocks as input, its almost done if i colud use python to print google search results(would find the rediff link there), i tried googpy but its outdated, can you please giude me on should i proceed..

Comment: i just got right for one input, working on list.. dont know for how long it will work .hope the site's structure doesnt much on a regular basis - .http://ideone.com/P6ZBu7